# Issue with grouping results from PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, grouping, html-select

I have an issue with a list, I would like to display groups and sub-groups (sgroups), something like:

```
GROUP1
sgroup1-a
sgroup1-b
sgroup1-c
sgroup1-d
GROUP2
sgroup2-a
sgroup2-b
```

But my code returns:

```
GROUP1
sgroup1-a
GROUP1
sgroup1-b
GROUP1
sgroup1-c
GROUP2
sgroup2-a
GROUP2
sgroup2-b
sgroup1-d
```

So I have name of groups displayed.

Tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groupe` (
`id_hm` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`groupe_tran` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`onoff` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0:no, 1:active',
`search` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'include in search menu, 0: 0ff, 1: on',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_hm`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sgroupe` (
`id_bm` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_hm1` tinyint(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'head menu id',
`sgroupe_tran` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`sgroupe_en` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`onoff` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0:no, 1:active',
`search` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'include in search menu, 0: 0ff, 1: on',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_bm`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=49 ;
```

Query and PHP code:

```
$sSel = 'SELECT DISTINCT(groupe_tran), sgroupe_tran FROM groupe JOIN sgroupe ON groupe.id_hm = sgroupe.id_hm1 WHERE groupe.search = "1" AND sgroupe.search = "1" AND groupe.onoff = "1" AND sgroupe.onoff = "1"';

$sReq = $connexion->query($sSel);
$sRes = $sReq->fetchAll();

echo '<select name="groupe">';
foreach ($sRes as $sV) {

    $groupe_tran = $sV['groupe_tran'];
    $sgroupe_tran = $sV['sgroupe_tran'];

    echo '<option value="' . $groupe_tran . '">' . $groupe_tran . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $sgroupe_tran . '">' . $sgroupe_tran . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: You could create a `$previous_groupe_tran` and check if the current is the same as the previous, and if not then print.

Comment: could you give me an example please, I could not find out how it works

Comment: posted an example as an answer.

Comment: [Fetch all rows grouped by a specific column using PDO and selecting all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40397344/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$groupe_tran` is your `GROUP1`/`GROUP2` value, you can save the previous `$groupe_tran` and check if the current value is not the same -

```
$sSel = 'SELECT DISTINCT(groupe_tran), sgroupe_tran FROM groupe JOIN sgroupe ON groupe.id_hm = sgroupe.id_hm1 WHERE groupe.search = "1" AND sgroupe.search = "1" AND groupe.onoff = "1" AND sgroupe.onoff = "1"';

$sReq = $connexion->query($sSel);
$sRes = $sReq->fetchAll();

// create a previous value
$previous_groupe_tran = '';

echo '<select name="groupe">';
foreach ($sRes as $sV) {

    $groupe_tran = $sV['groupe_tran'];
    $sgroupe_tran = $sV['sgroupe_tran'];

    // check if current matches previous, and only print if no match    
    if($groupe_tran != $previous_groupe_tran){

        echo '<option value="' . $groupe_tran . '">' . $groupe_tran . '</option>';

        // set previous to current
        $previous_groupe_tran = $groupe_tran;
    }

    echo '<option value="' . $sgroupe_tran . '">' . $sgroupe_tran . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your example and added array_push:

```
    $previous_groupe_tran = array();

echo '<select name="hmenu">';
foreach ($sRes as $sV) {

$groupe_tran = $sV['groupe_tran'];
$sgroupe_tran = $sV['sgroupe_tran'];

if(!in_array($groupe_tran, $previous_groupe_tran)){
array_push($previous_groupe_tran, $groupe_tran);
print_r($previous_groupe_tran);
echo '<option value="' . $groupe_tran . '">'.$id_hm.' - ' . $groupe_tran . '</option>';
    }

    echo '<option value="' . $sgroupe_tran . '">'.$id_hm1.' - ' . $sgroupe_tran . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO's fetching flags to build nested rows beneath an associative first level of data.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/24))

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT groupe_tran,
       sgroupe_tran
FROM groupe
JOIN sgroupe ON groupe.id_hm = sgroupe.id_hm1 
WHERE groupe.search = 1
  AND sgroupe.search = 1
  AND groupe.onoff = 1
  AND sgroupe.onoff = 1
SQL;

echo "<select name=\"groupe\">\n";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $k => $rows) {
        echo "<option>$k</option>\n";
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo "<option>{$row['sgroupe_tran']}</option>\n";
        }
    }
echo '</select>';
```

Output:

```
<select name="groupe">
<option>GROUP1</option>
<option>sgroup1-a</option>
<option>sgroup1-b</option>
<option>sgroup1-c</option>
<option>sgroup1-d</option>
<option>GROUP2</option>
<option>sgroup2-a</option>
<option>sgroup2-b</option>
</select>
```

<sub>Might you want to use `optgroup` tags?</sub>