# Fetch all rows grouped by a specific column using PDO and selecting all columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use PDO's `fetchAll()` method with `\PDO::FETCH_GROUP` option.

However `\PDO::FETCH_GROUP` uses the first column as key to group the results. The query I have selects all fields like:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`;
```

The table `my_table` has quite a few fields and it is very possible that new fields to be added in the future. I don't like the idea to specify all fields in the query one by one.

The table looks like that:

```
| my_table |
+----------+
| id       |
| type     |
| a_field  |
| b_field  |
| ...      |
```

Is there any possibility to use `SELECT * FROM my_table` and group by the `type` field?

I've tried the following query but it threw an exception:

```
$sql = "SELECT type, * FROM my_table";
$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `my_table` WHERE type IN ('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC')' at line 1' in MyClass.php on line XXX

Comment: *What* exception it threw? Ok, you don't bother to read what it says, but can you at least post it here, to let other people have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the exception. Surely I did read the exception, and I think the query is not a valid SQL using `type, *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just prepend the asterisk with the table name:

```
$sql = "SELECT type, my_table.* FROM my_table";
$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```